# Solved: redirect to another page using functions.php

Tags: functions, redirect

I want users to change their avatar on a general site, because some plugins only work with that.
for example

> www.example.com/members/user1/profile/change-avatar/

And

> www.example.com/members/user2/profile/change-avatar/

Should both redirect to

> www.example.com/change-avatar/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.

```
add_action('init','redirect_to_change_avatar');

function redirect_to_change_avatar() {
    if ( strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/profile/change-avatar/') !== false ) {
        wp_redirect('/change-avatar/');
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend something a little more robust for your logic, that way if the URL changes you aren't still using the same position arguments:

```php
function redirect_to_change_avatar() {
    $request_uri = filter_input( INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_URI', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

    // Strpos will return boolean FALSE if the string does not match at all.
    // N.B the strict === comparison:
    if ( false === strpos( $request_uri, '/profile/change-avatar/' )) {
        return;
    }

    wp_redirect( '/change-avatar/' );
    exit;
}
```